# video streaming on imx6 board using gstreamer and RTSP server

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-0.10

I am working on yocto project imx6 board and having problem with video streaming, gstreamer and RTSP server is successfully installed on board.

after this command

```
"gst-launch -v \rtspsrc latency=300 location=rtsp://10.55.165.
128:9001/1.mp4 name=s ! \ rtph264depay ! queue ! mfw_h264decoder ! xvimagesink
"
```

I got an error as follow:

```
H264D_ARM11_02.06.03  build on Apr 16 2013 13:30:59.
MFW_GST_H264_DECODER_PLUGIN 3.0.11 build on Sep 19 2016 13:40:12.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
/home/user/vvdn_sdk/stct_iog1/source/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/gst-plugins-base/0.10.36-r8/gst-:
Could not open display
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
root@imx6slzbha:~#
```

If any one have idea then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use `mfw_isink` or `mfw_v4l2src` hope is works